# How can I save a template and download it from the database using smarty template engine

Tags: php, smarty

I'm having a hard time saving my template to a database and download the contents to view using Smarty.

I followed the tutorial on Smarty.net on how to make a custom retrieve type.

My original method was save the tpl markup to the db then download it and pass it as a variable to a smarty assigned variable and in my text.pl do something like {$source}

but this parses it as a string and smarty won't compile it.

the tutorial on smarty website didn't help and just leaves me with more questions...

this is what i tried based on the tutorial

```
function db_get_template($tpl_name, &$tpl_source, &$s)
{
    $tpl_name = "index.tpl";
    $tpl_source = nl2br($defaults->get_default_theme('theme_data'));
    return true;
}
function db_get_timestamp($tpl_name, &$tpl_timestamp, &$smarty)
{
    $tpl_timestamp = (int)time();
    //$tpl_timestamp = (int)$defaults->get_default_theme('modified_on');
    return true;
}

function db_get_secure($tpl_name, &$smarty)
{
    // assume all templates are secure
    return true;
}

function db_get_trusted($tpl_name, &$smarty)
{
    // not used for templates 
}
$s->registerResource("db", array( 
    "db_get_template",
    "db_get_secure",
    "db_get_trusted"
));
$s->display("db:index.tpl");
```

i'm not sure where db:index.tpl is being pulled from. I don't know where the markup is suppose to be loaded into...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dirty even suggesting this, but:

[Here's a more relevant manual page](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/template.resources.tpl) than the [page you were referencing](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.resources.tpl).

In particular, pay attention to the `string:` prefix to the "filename" passed in the `display` method call.  You can simply pull the template data out of your database (a horrible idea, IMNSHO) and pass it to Smarty that way.  No need to build your own custom resource thing unless you *really* want to do it that way.

I, for one, would urge you to keep it as stupid, ugly and obvious as possible, as to remind yourself about how much of a horrible, no-good idea this is.  I'd like to remind you that Smarty *compiles to PHP*, and placing Smarty code in the database is an effective gateway to arbitrary code execution, a severe security vulnerability.

Comment: i seen this too, what im confused is how to show the tpl source. Where do i output it and how.

Comment: What do you mean "show the tpl source"?  What do you mean "where do I ouput it"?  Those statements are not understandable.  Please re-read the first linked documentation page again, and try setting up an example to understand how it works.  It should fit your requirement.

Comment: hehe, ya sorry i clicked on the wrong link you provided. But ya man, this completely solved my problem!